# trying to do email confirmation after user registration and getting error "Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Auth' not found

Tags: email, authentication, laravel-5.5, registration, confirmation

### Here is my `VerifyUserbyEmail` custom middle-ware

Can any one please help to sort it out ?
while I have used namespace properly but still getting error

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Http\Middleware\Auth;

use Closure;

class VerifyUserbyEmail 
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = \App\User::findOrFail(Auth::id());
        if ($user->status == 0){
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('login')->with('messege', 'you need to verify your account, check your email');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
use App\Http\Middleware\Auth;
```

with

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Comment: but got another error when trying to confirm(along with two parameters email and token on Url) after registration  
here is the error
"Class App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController does not exist"

Comment: RegisterController is usually stored in "Class\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController "

Comment: locate where the error is coming from and change the link to the above

Comment: yeah tried to locate the error but could'nt get where exactly error comming from because i have also checked namespace it's also fine

Comment: could you please help bit more that where exactly the error is ?

Comment: What if you search for the occurrence of 'RegisterController' in the whole project folder, and publish the exception and the results in a new question.  =)

Comment: well there is only register controller in whole project namespaced as following app\http\controllers\Auth